# Changing an value in an R table based on its value in a scond table

Tags: r, replace

I have two data frames.
Table 1 has a list of observations and variables.
Table 2 has a list of unique values for a variable and a value for that unique set of variables.

```
df1                         df2 (distinct values for variable A)
A    B    C    D    E               1    .6    
1    etc. . .                       2    .3
2    etc. . . .                     3    .1
1    etc. . . . 
1
3
2
```

I want to replace the value of variable A in df1 
with its probability from df2

How can I do this?  I've tried using for if statements with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
df1$A <- df2$col2[match(df1$A, df2$col1)]
df1
#   A
#1 0.6
#2 0.3
#3 0.6
#4 0.6
#5 0.1
#6 0.3
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2))
 df2 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2= c(.6, .3, .1))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks so much.  Only thing I would add is that the columns have to be of the same data type.  df1$A  and df2$col1 have to both be numeric or character.  I got around it by creating an extra variable - I can pair down the dataset later.  =)